# Table exhibit different behavior between ie and chrome, Its height difference 8px

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, border, css-tables

Table exhibit different behavior between Ii and chrome, Its height difference 8px:

```
.table {
    border-top: 1px solid #B1B5BA;
    border-left: 1px solid #B1B5BA;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

see also: http://jsfiddle.net/r569594043/Pv7HH/.

I'm simulating an Excel,but the left header of the `table` not the same.
see: http://wxrequestingsongs.sinaapp.com/1.png, I think is the border of the `td` cause this.

Comment: You should post code (preferably minimal code) that is sufficient for reproducing the problem. A mere CSS rule is surely not enough, especially when it does not contain the part that you suspect to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/r569594043/Pv7HH/

Comment: Providing a jsfiddle is a nice addition, but not sufficient. You should include actual code in the question itself. Besides, the height of a table depends on many, many things, and you should do at least some preliminary analysis and tell the results, instead of expecting others to do all the debugging.